# Best way to .clean and .strip long string?

Tags: python, string, list

> Desired Outcome Is = ["This", "is", "a", "random", "sentence"]

```
text = "Th,is is a? random!! sentence..."  # Eddied, added comma inside word 

clean_text = text.split()

for clean in clean_text:

    double_clean_text = clean.strip(",.!?")

    print(double_clean_text)
```

Managed to clean, but how do I get it all back to list??

Is this is efficient way to do it?

Comment: initiate a new list `new_list = []` before the loop and `.append()` to it in the loop (or use a comprehension)

Comment: Another option would be to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) or a series of [`string.replace`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) followed by a single `.split()` (though this will remove the target characters *anywhere* in the string, not just at the beginning/end of each word).

Answer (score 2):

You can do the below:

```
print(" ".join([clean.strip(",.!?") for clean in clean_text]))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use list comprehension:

```
print([t.strip(",.!?") for t in text.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clean_text = text.split()
print([clean.strip(",.!?") for clean in clean_text])
```

OR

```
clean_text = text.split()
res = []
for clean in clean_text:
    double_clean_text = clean.strip(",.!?")
    res.append(double_clean_text)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use regular expression `"\w+"` to find all words:

```
import re

result = re.findall("\w+", text)
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that `\w` will not match accented chars, unless compiled accordingly

Comment: @UriGoren, in newer versions of python it will.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning to a new variable, assign the cleaned result back to the list.

```
text = "This, is a? random!! sentence..."

clean_text = text.split()

for i, clean in enumerate(clean_text):

    clean_text[i] = clean.strip(",.!?")
```

Then you can use `' '.join` to (mostly) restore the list to its original form:

```
cleaned_text = ' '.join(clean_text)
```

I say "mostly", because `split` erases information about how *many* spaces were removed from the original string, which may be fine, but is worth being aware of.

The whole thing can be written using a single list comprehension.

```
clean_text = ' '.join([clean.strip(",.!?") for clean in text.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `re` and simply put `r'\w+'` greedily captures all alpha characters.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "This, is a? random!! sentence..."
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', text)
['This', 'is', 'a', 'random', 'sentence']
```

Or you could use `str.strip` and `str.split` and an easy way to supply all punctuation to strip is using [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation). This will split the text by whitespace then remove all punctuation from each sub string.

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> text = "This, is a? random!! sentence..."
>>> [s.strip(punctuation) for s in text.split()]
['This', 'is', 'a', 'random', 'sentence']
```

Comment: Second does not work if for instance "," is in the middle of word. ```text = "This, is a? random!! sent,,,,,,ence..."```

Comment: That was not specified in the question

Answer (score 0):

Since you already good pretty good answers, I'd like to introduce regular expressions

```
import re
text = "This, is a? random!! sentence..."
clean_list = re.split('[.,?! ]+', text)
```

Where the chars inside the square brackets are the chars you want to split by and strip

Comment: But there are dozens of spaces. And punctuation singns.

Comment: `from string import punctuation`

Comment: Don't see this in your answer. And what about spaces?

Comment: `from string import whitespace`
But I'm a bit confused what you're looking for, if you know what is the list of allowed chars - use it (like `\w`), if you know the list of separators, use it (like `.,?!`) in my example